# Must i release object at here?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

I've confused about memory management of Objective-C.
Example:

```
.h file
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *myString;

.m file
@synthesize myString
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arrayString count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  //in this case,i have to check 
  if(self.myString != nil)
        [myString release],self.myString = nil;
  //and assign 
  self.myString = [arrayString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  //or i need only assign 
  self.myString = [arrayString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Can anyone explain to me?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to release, because the property is defined as "retain", that means it retains the passed object after it releases the previous one.

If, instead of accessing the property you use directly the variable then you need to manually manage the release/retain..

BTW: you can send a message to a nil object...(so without checking it is nil to release it)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to assign the string .. and release/assign it to `nil` in the `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload` methods.

Comment: You don't even necessarily need to call release. Since it is a property with the `retain` qualifier, you simply need to assign the property to nil: `self.myString = nil;`

Comment: why? i've a property with the retain,and i've never assign it to other,but when i call [myProperty release] at dealloc or didUnload without crash.at here,retainCount is 0 but i can release it.i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(self.myString != nil){
        [myString release],self.myString = nil;
 }
```

This is enough:

```
  if(self.myString != nil){
            self.myString = nil;
     }
```

As for your question, you only need this:

```
  self.myString = [arrayString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: also `self.myString = nil;` is enough